# Representing an Integer as a Sum of at Most $k$ Triangular Numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, summation, sums-of-squares

What is the smallest $k$ such that every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ can be represented by a sum of exactly $k$ triangular numbers?  For the sake of simplicity, I will assume $0$ is a triangular number.

I've been able to establish that $3 \le k \le 8$.  The lower bound was found through experimentation.  The upper bound is a consequence of Waring's problem, and also the neat property that two consecutive triangular numbers always sum to a square.

Any ideas on how to obtain more reasonable bounds on $k$?  Or perhaps even some obvious method to determine $k$ which I have overlooked?

Related Question(s):

- [Representing a number as a sum of at most $k$ squares.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/72378/representing-a-number-as-a-sum-of-at-most-k-squares)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

THREE.

Multiply by 8. Add 3. It is a theorem of Gauss and Legendre that every $8n+3$ is the sum of three odd squares.

SEE, from the book *The Sensual Quadratic Form* by John Horton Conway, pages 138,139,140:

[image]

A list from a book by Dickson, giving sums $f(x,y,z) = a x^2 + b y^2 + c z^2$ with $1 \leq a \leq b \leq c,$ and all the numbers that cannot be expressed by that one. So, $a=b=c=1,$ we find that the sum of three squares $x^2 + y^2 + z^2$ represents every positive integer not of the form $4^k \, (8n+7).$ In particular, all $8n + 3$ are represented.

[image]

Comment: I'm confused, I don't see why it is relevant to know that every $8n+3$ is the sum of three odd squares.  Is this somehow related to the case of triangular numbers?

Comment: @Ryan $$n = \frac{a(a+1)}{2} + \frac{b(b+1)}{2} + \frac{c(c+1)}{2} \iff 8 n + 3 = (2a+1)^2 + (2b+1)^2 + (2c+1)^2$$ IMHO, this observation is really smart.

Answer (score 2):

According to a [theorem of Fermat-Legendre-Gauss-Cauchy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_polygonal_number_theorem), any integer can be written as the sum of at most $n$ $n$-gonal numbers. This generalizes Lagrange's theorem on sums of four squares.

(Remark that Fermat's conjecture makes no claim that $n$ is optimal. For instance it is conjectured that every positive integer is the sum of at most 7 octahedral numbers. However, it is easy to see that 3 is optimal for triangular numbers.)