# The number of sums of 5 or more squares

Tags: number-theory, reference-request

Let $r_k(n)$ be the number of ways to write $n$ as the sum of $k$ squares of integers.

> **Theorem:** If $k \ge 5$ then there are constants $C,c>0$ such that for any $n$, $$cn^{k/2 - 1} \le r_k(n) \le Cn^{k/2 - 1}$$

What is the simplest way to prove it as stated? I am especially interested in the lower bound. Is there a recommended book on the subject?

I have read about the Hardy-Littlewood circle method in E. Grosswald's *Representations of Integers as Sums of Squares*, but it seems to give a much more precise formula than what I need, and I feel there's a chance it might be simpler than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A proof can be found [here](http://users.wfu.edu/rouseja/cv/sumsofsqrs), in the artilce of Jeremy Rouse. It uses the "singular series" which gives the estimates, i.e.,
$r_k(n) \asymp n^{k/2-1}$, for even $k$. For more references in the literature, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/72378/representing-a-number-as-a-sum-of-at-most-k-squares), in particular the answer of Greg Martin.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So basically, all of these proofs rely on the Hardy-Littlewood circle method + showing that the singular series is bounded. Am I correct in understanding that there is no simpler approach, even if I don't care about the values of the constants $C,c$ but only about their existence?